# Calling a function only known at runtime

Tags: rust

I want to do my first try at a Rust application by doing an input validation server which can validate values from an AJAX request. This means I need a way to use a JSON configuration file to specify which validation functions are used based on the name of the input values and perhaps a form name which come in at runtime in an HTTP request. How can I do something similar to PHP's call_user_function_array in Rust?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add references to functions to a `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Add appropriate logic
fn validate_str(_: &str) -> bool { true }
fn validate_bool(_: &str) -> bool { true }

fn main() {
    let mut methods: HashMap<_, fn(&str) -> bool> = HashMap::new();

    methods.insert("string", validate_str);
    methods.insert("boolean", validate_bool);

    let input = [("string", "alpha"), ("boolean", "beta")];

    for (kind, value) in &input {
        let valid = match methods.get(kind) {
            Some(f) => f(value),
            None => false,
        };

        println!("'{}' is a valid {}? {}", value, kind, valid);
    }
}
```

The only tricky part here is the line `let mut methods: HashMap<_, fn(&str) -> bool> = HashMap::new()`. You need to define that that map will have values that are *function* pointers. Each function has its own unique, anonymous type, and function pointers are an abstraction on top of that.

Comment: Ah nice so the reference to the function would be stored similar to how you might do so in Javascript. One part of the syntax I don't have a complete understanding of is what is between the angle brackets. I get that it makes certain at compile time that the values assigned to the hash are indeed function pointers but I can't find anything similar to that syntax in Rust examples in particular the `<_,` part. What is the signficance of the underscore in that syntax?

Comment: `_` tells the compiler to infer the type (in this case, `&str`) instead of having you to write it manually. See for more examples: http://is.gd/qiJUtJ

Comment: Okay thank you very much for the help. Makes me excited about building things in Rust. I have quite a few ideas. Being primarily a Ruby, PHP and Javascript coder this is a somewhat new world for me.